# htaccess + wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I'm working with updated WP and I'm trying to redirect old url to new url:

```
Redirect 301 /es/ http://www.example.com
Redirect 301 /es/tienda/ http://www.example.com
Redirect 301 /es/categoria-producto/quillas/center http://www.example.com/categoria/quillas-single/
```

And this is what I got in the browser:

If I try to access to the first URL I got a redirect to:

```
http://www.example.comtienda/
```

Yes, It's missing the slash.

And If I try to access the other URL I got a redirect to:

```
http://www.example.com/categoria-producto/quillas/center/
```

Which is a 404...

So, I migrated the website thinking about server error but the problem persists...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: reset your permalink

Comment: Server configuration questions are off topic here and should be asked on serverfault.com but your question is also incomplete by not showing your server configuration.

Comment: @Rob This isn't a server-config question?!

Comment: @w3dk Are you saying modifying the .htaccess file is not a server configuration?

Comment: @Rob Whilst `.htaccess` files are "per-directory Apache config files", they are part of userland development and only really required when you don't have access to the main server config. This would be considered off-topic on ServerFault, where the majority of `.htaccess` questions get closed as being duplicates of a catch-all question. If you aren't a sys admin and have full access to the server config then any question of this nature is strictly off-topic on ServerFault - the only ones that get answered (and not closed) are the ones that slip through the net.

Comment: @w3dk It doesn't matter. Duplicate questions should be closed and non-programming questions are off topic here despite what serverfault does. You should not answer off-topic questions per the FAQ.

Comment: Thanks for your atention mates, all the answer are valuable for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect 301 /es/ http://www.example.com
> Redirect 301 /es/tienda/ http://www.example.com
> Redirect 301 /es/categoria-producto/quillas/center http://www.example.com/categoria/quillas-single/
> ```

Since the mod_alias `Redirect` directive is prefix matching, you would need to reverse these directives. But you are missing the slash on the end of the target URL, so that's why the slash is missing. So, for example:

```
Redirect 301 /es/categoria-producto/quillas/center/ http://www.example.com/categoria/quillas-single/
Redirect 301 /es/tienda/ http://www.example.com/
Redirect 301 /es/ http://www.example.com/
```

If you have a slash on the source URL, you should include a slash on the target.

However, since this is a WordPress site, you should be using mod_rewrite instead. For example, before your existing WP directives:

```
RewriteRule ^es/categoria-producto/quillas/center$ /categoria/quillas-single/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^es/tienda/$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^es/$ / [R=301,L]
```

In this case the order of the directives does not matter.

Comment: Thank you @w3dk, you save my day!

Comment: I didn't vote you down mate, You help me a lot and I pushed the "up" button, but I'm < 15 reputation. I don't understand who give this answer down vote